# Joomla Select where 'column' in array

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I have the following query for joomla:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('name','username','depto')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__users','a'))
->join('RIGHT', $db->quoteName('#__comprofiler','b').'ON('.$db->quoteName('a.id').' = '.$db->quoteName('b.id').')')
->where($db->quoteName('depto').' IN '.$db->quoteName(array($my_array)))
->order($db->quoteName('name'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

In $my_array I have an array of values which I want to use to filter my results, such as in:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE depto IN ($my_array)";
```

I did try to use implode, but I got no results at all.

```
$my_array = implode(",",$my_array);
```

Anyone knows how to use the db-> escape for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have quoteName here, you are not quoting a name:

```
$db->quoteName(array($my_array)))
```

You need

```
. ' (' . implode(',', $my_array) . ')'
```

Also I wanted to add that if the reason you were using `quoteName()` is that the array is an array of strings, you need to plan this out a bit more.  First you should use quote() because that is what you use to get the correct quotations of strings. But second, you are going to have to plan out the implode better so that you get `$db->quote()` wrapped around each element in the array. Fortunately $db->quote() accepts an array as input. So  what you really want to do is something more like this

```
. ' (' . $db->quote($my_array) . '")'
```

Comment: Is something like this you mean? I did $my_array = implode(",",$my_array); and than used the imploded array in the query, like this: ->where($db->quoteName('depto').' IN ('.$db->quote($my_array).')') but still no results returning. I have strings with accents, could this been messing my query?

Comment: It shouldn't be if you have the quoting correct.    I think you ned to put a space before the IN if you don't have one (`' IN ('`    ... try adding $query->dump() and see what you get for the rendered query.  you will also be better off if you use the whole query api.  Do you have debugging turned on?

Comment: `$db->quoteName('#__comprofiler','b').'ON('.$db->quoteName('a.id')`  that is going to give you `jos_comprofilerON(a.id`  (if jos is your prefix)/

Comment: You can't implode the array and then db->quote it .. you say you have $my_array= array('a','b','c'), implode give you $my_array='a,b,c' and then you quote it you will get  `IN ('a,b,c')  which is a single string that you will try to match.  WHat you want is `IN ('a','b','c')`  and that is going to be gotten as I said befor by instead having `$my_array= array('a','b','c') ...IN ($db->quote($my_array))`.   $db->quote will handle the imploding for your properly.

Comment: Thanks! that was one of the mistakes. Doing the implode("','",$my_array), I got all value wrapped in single quote marks. But I got something else wrong, the query was selecting all row, but not those which had the values in $my_array. So I had to use a NOT IN, and now it's working, but I got confused about why this happened.

Comment: Well, I think this query is getting results where is empty (and not null). Have this warning and nothing more: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /my_domais/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 150

Comment: When printing print_r($db->quote($my_array)), I have this kind of result: '\'Value1\',\'Value2\',\'Last value\''

Comment: What is it like in the database? YOu may need to tell quote not to escape, hard for me to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE depto IN ('".implode("', '", $my_array)."')";
```